# Fatal error: Call to a member function setCustomerId() on boolean in /app/code/Ced/CsMarketplace/Controller/Account/CreatePassword.php:78

Tags: magento2, multi-vendor

This occurs when a Vendor clicks the forgotten password link on the front end; they are sent an email with a link to click and when they click the link in the email a page open with this error.

```
<?php

namespace Ced\CsMarketplace\Controller\Account;

use Ced\CsMarketplace\Model\AccountManagement;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class CreatePassword extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface
 */
protected $accountManagement;

/**
 * @var Session
 */
protected $session;

/**
 * @var PageFactory
 */
protected $resultPageFactory;

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param Session $customerSession
 * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 * @param AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Session $customerSession,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    AccountManagement $accountManagement
) {
     $registry = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
    
    $this->session = $customerSession;
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
    if(!$registry->registry('vendorPanel'))
        $registry->register('vendorPanel', 1);
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * Resetting password handler
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
 */
public function execute()
{
    $resetPasswordToken = (string)$this->getRequest()->getParam('token');
    $customerId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $isDirectLink = $resetPasswordToken != '' && $customerId != 0;
    if (!$isDirectLink) {
        $resetPasswordToken = (string)$this->session->getRpToken();
        $customerId = (int)$this->session->getRpCustomerId();
    }

    try {
        $this->accountManagement->validateResetPasswordLinkToken($customerId, $resetPasswordToken);
        if ($isDirectLink) {
        
            $this->session->setRpToken($resetPasswordToken);
            $this->session->setRpCustomerId($customerId);
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/createpassword');
            return $resultRedirect;
        } else {
        
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
            $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('vendor.resetPassword')->setCustomerId($customerId)
                ->setResetPasswordLinkToken($resetPasswordToken);
            return $resultPage;
        }
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__('Your password reset link has expired.'));
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/forgotpassword');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: have you checked your $customerId variable value? It should contain customer ID but is boolean

Comment: Check this statement $customerId = (int)$this->session->getRpCustomerId();